# Reflection of light inside glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I am trying to get clear glass material. There is to much reflection on glass. How can I fix this reflection of light.
[image]
Edit:- I tried fixing outer glass. Please help fixing the bulb glass bit accurate.

Edit :- How to avoid this light sphere.
[image]

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe show some screenshots of your object and material, maybe you could mix your glass material with another one, or use an Input > Light Path node, etc

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: mmh I'm not sure what's happening, maybe share your file (only the lamp)?

Comment: You can download it from here https://we.tl/t-Dehybysf9c

Comment: That blend file doesn't include any materials at all so we have no idea what settings you are using. Please share a file with your materials via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it

Comment: I uploaded the blend file. Please check.

Comment: One for @moonboots to look at I think. It looks pretty well the same as your left-hand image here. Certainly nothing like the right-hand one. (Using Blender 3.6.4)

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the glass BSDF shader consist mainly of the values `roughness` and `IOR`. An `IOR´ is meaningless without a volume within which the` IOR` applies.
Your light bulb and the glass windows of the lamp are just surfaces and planes. Thus the glass shader lacks important properties on which it can operate.

Give the bulb and especially the glass windows (since the reflection problem is primarily one of the glass windows) a thickness so that the glass material can actually behave like a glass.

The easiest way to achieve this is the `solidify` modifier.

I'm not sure if that alone will solve your problem, but I'm sure that *without* such a change (giving the glass a thickness, a volume) you will never get a realistic representation.

Comment: Yeah, I gave thickness to glass window it is fine. But bulb is not working fine.

Comment: "But bulb is not working fine."
What does that mean?

Comment: When I added light in bulb it's creating Light sphere. How to avoid it. I attached image in question.

Comment: Hello, please try to keep your question in a consistent form. It is okay to improve a question by further editing it, but it should always be clear to a new reader: what is your Problem? What is your Question? You added your recent image *above* the others. Please make clear that this already **is** a later image with changes intruced by an answer, and there is still need for further improvement.
Lastly: What did you do with the bulb so that now there is this sphere? I can't imagine this is the result of appling a solidify modifier?

Comment: I will make it clear. I was in bit hurry so I just added the image and didn't checked the where it was placed. I didn't did much just added point light in the bulb. I there any way we can remove that sphere without removing light.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the reflection of the *Point* light, maybe you should disable the *Multiple Importance* option which seems to make the *Point* reflection invisible and instead use an *Emission* node for the bulb material so that you keep a bright object. You won't see the filament anymore though, you could use an *Input > Geometry* node, *Backfacing* output as a factor to keep the filament visible, and use an *Emission* for the filament as well.